# How to fix double directory when get TreeView of folder and files in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, treeview, root

I create a TreeView of folders and files in C# Winform, this is my source code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public partial class WindowExplorer : Form
{
    public void LoadFile(TreeNode parent, string path)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string dirName = new FileInfo(path).Name;
            TreeNode dirNode = new TreeNode(dirName);
            parent.Nodes.Add(dirNode);
            string[] subDir = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            string[] subFile = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            string[] allSubItem = subDir.Concat(subFile).ToArray();
            foreach (string subItem in allSubItem)
            {
                LoadFile(dirNode, subItem);
            }
        }
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string fileName = new FileInfo(path).Name;
            TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode(fileName);
            parent.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
        }
    }

    private void WindowExplorer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "D:\\Laravel";
        TreeNode dNode = new TreeNode(new FileInfo(path).Name);
        fileView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dNode);
        LoadFile(dNode, path);
    }
}
```

The `Nodes[0]` is "My Computer" node.
I just test with root is "D:\Laravel", and here is result:

[image: TreeView Nodes]

As you see, the "Laravel" folder appears twice.
I can't fix it, although I have tried remove `fileView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dNode);` but not working.

Comment: You do not need to Add in the method  WindowExplorer_Load since it is also being added in LoadFile

Answer (score 0):

In the Load event handler, you first create a Node, add it to the existing Root Node (`My Computer`), then you pass that Node to the `LoadFile()` method.
This ne Node becomes the Root Node, `TreeNode parent`, when passed to the method, which adds a new Node to it using the `string path` argument, so the Root Node is duplicated.

You can preserve the Root Node, passing it to the method, along with the Path value that becomes the new child Node or the Root Node, e.g.,

```
private void WindowExplorer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "D:\\Laravel";

    // Clear the TreeView if necessary / preferable:  
    //  fileView.Nodes.Clear();
    //  var root = fileView.Nodes.Add("My Computer");
    //  LoadFile(root, path);

    LoadFile(fileView.Nodes[0], path);
}
```

Your `LoadFile()` method could use some refactoring, since it generates a whole lot of strings and queries (*synchronously*) the file system twice in the same procedure.

You could use the [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos) method, to retrive both files and directories at the same time, use the file attribute to determine whether the file has the `FileAttributes.Directory` attribute and also order by file name.

Note that the loop is performed over an `IOrderedEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>` collection, so the loop operates while the enumeration is still ongoing.

```
public void LoadFile(TreeNode parent, string path)
{
    var dir = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(path));
    parent.Nodes.Add(dir);

    var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFileSystemInfos()
        .OrderBy(fsi => fsi.Attributes).ThenBy(fsi => fsi.Name);

    foreach (var file in files) {
        // If the current file is a Directory, recurse its content
        if (file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)) {
            LoadFile(dir, file.FullName);
        }
        else {
            // Not a directory, add the file to the current Node
            dir.Nodes.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
}
```